# Is there a way to create an "inline-none" CSS effect? Will be hidden, but preserve the space it takes up on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I would like to be able to hide some buttons (in the right column of a 3 column table display). I would like to

```
  <tr id="a_row_<?php echo $a_id ?>">
    <td id="linked_general_name_<?php echo $a_id ?>"><a target="_blank" href="index.php?general_assessments&stats=<?php echo $a_id ?>"><?php echo $label ?></a></td>
    <td><a href="index.php?viewcompany&id=<?php echo $c_id ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $c_name ?></a></td>
    <td class="text-right" style="vertical-align:middle;">
      <a templateID="<?php echo $a_id ?>" href="#" class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-cogs" style="padding-right:5px;"></i>Create Template</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Well, what I am doing is using jQuery to hide the templateID attribute items. I also use this so that I can basically take the ID from the link and use it to populate a modal (Don't worry, this is for a single user admin panel).

Here is the jQuery...

```
$("#something").on("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); // works as intended
 var aID = $(this).attr("templateID"); // works as intended
 $("[templateID]").css("display", "none"); // this works ~ hides all buttons
 // more stuff below... 
});

$("#somethingElse").on("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); // works as intended
 $("[templateID]").css("display", "block"); // this works ~ shows all buttons
});
```

The problem? When I hide the buttons, it makes the 2 other columns shift to the right because the 3rd column is no longer taking up as much space. I want to be able to produce the same results as inline-block or table-row for when you work with a whole TR & want to show something, but with a table CELL / inner contents of that cell for HIDING it. Is there anything such as inner-none, or table-row-none? I can't find anything that works. I don't want to remove the column. The ONLY reason the button is being hidden is because the container that it is in (table) fades out when a button is clicked, and I hide the buttons so a super quick double click can't occur - If the buttons stay visible, I've found you can click extremely fast (it's hard, but leads to a bug) and mess up the fade animation due to fadeToggle() in use.

Anyways, if anyone knows how I can hide a table cell contents (for a whole column) WITHOUT the rest of table moving (being responsive to nothing in 3rd column), that would be wonderful. thank you :)

Comment: Use `visibility: hidden` instead.

Comment: You can use also  `opacity:0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the space while hidding the element you can either use `visibility: hidden` or `opacity:0` and to make it visible again `visibility:visible` or `opacity:1`

```
 $("#something").on("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); // works as intended
     var aID = $(this).attr("templateID"); // works as intended
     $("[templateID]").css("visibility", "hidden"); // this works ~ hides all buttons
     // more stuff below... 
    });

$("#somethingElse").on("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); // works as intended
 $("[templateID]").css("visibility", "visible"); // this works ~ shows all buttons
});
```

Comment: Yeah, perfect. Thank you. Easy answer to an annoying issue. Exactly the type of CSS attribute I was looking for. Forgot about those guys :)